# Converting string to datetime in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a column with a `string` representing a datetime, where the month name is 3 letters, and there's the time zone info. How do I convert it into a `datetime`?

"Jul 13 2020 23:05:58 GMT"  --> 2020-07-13T23:05:58.000

Answer (score 9):

This will create a table with a single string column, with a single sample record (for the sake of answering your question)

```
.set Ts <| print s = "Jul 13 2020 23:05:58 GMT"
```

This will convert each string value in that column/table from `string` to `datetime`

```
Ts
| extend dt = todatetime(s)
```

[image]

relevant docs:

- [todatetime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/todatetimefunction)
- [supported `datetime` formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats)

Answer (score 2):

Simpler way of doing what Yoni suggested:

```
print dt = todatetime("Jul 13 2020 23:05:58 GMT")
```