# Convert string into date values

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-log-analytics

My data set contain timestamp with the following format :  '8/27/2023  11:00:00 AM'
Which are being converted into 'long'  when ingested to ADX (and look like this :  "['8_27_2023 11_00']"
How can I convert them into datetimes via KQL ?

Comment: your date format does not seem to be available in [Converting string to datetime in KQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62986694/converting-string-to-datetime-in-kql)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results:

**`Input:`**

[image]

If column type is long use tostring() in first replace_string(),else no need to use it.

To change to datetime use the below **`KQL Query`** which worked for me:

```
 let x= datatable(col1: string)
[
    "['8_27_2023 11_00']" 
];
x
|extend col2=replace_string(col1,"['","")
|extend col3=replace_string(col2,"']","")
|extend co=split(col3," ")
|extend col4=replace_string(tostring(co[0]),"_","/")
|extend col5=replace_string(tostring(co[1]),"_",":")
|project-away col2,col3,co
|extend changedto_date_coll=todatetime(strcat(col4," ",col5))
|project-away col4,col5
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32QywrCMBBF9/mKkI0WIrZpRVH6JaWEmA5aiU2pA1bw451EfCImm8Cdc7gTB8jHkjcG6W4dTK132ZqfcGi7XcIqxumIarLSaqlVqnKeZTpNJ7XgrN6wkV1hROgaTpwqB%20idsaDveHRJgoUUInmfzH9MKinI%20jVZnnrXYohzKfinpPiWoH/aqrROpNCkm39Ci39Q9oDWAeoHfwCLM3M2l7iejDWsf/n2pttBg17T/4Gm2JXowxvbI0xJbE0sX4TyAV8kP8RFTG6CbE4yigEAAA==)

Comment: @AdiK, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're confident that the string won't change structure and you're ingesting this a lot it could make sense to functionalise it.

```
let T = datatable (timestamp:string)[
@"['8_27_2023 11_00']",
@"['12_30_1970 13_00']",
@"['10_31_2060 15_00']"
];
let getdatetimefromtimestamp = (t:string) {
let T1 = split(trim_start('\\[\'', trim_end('\']', t)), ' ');
let DatePart = split(T1[0], '_');
let TimePart = split(T1[1], '_');
make_datetime(toint(DatePart[-1]), toint(DatePart[0]), toint(DatePart[1]), toint(TimePart[0]), toint(TimePart[1]))
};
T
| extend timestamp = getdatetimefromtimestamp(timestamp)
```